# Assigning a function to a string with the function's name in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a function assigned to a variable, `func`. `func` contains the function itself (ie. `print func` returns `<function func at 0x103f25410>`

I have a simple class:

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self, data):
    # init code
        pass
    def func(self):
        pass
    def dunc(self):
        pass
```

Let's say in `__init__` I received `func` in `data` and can access it as `data.func`. I could assign that to consume by `self.consume = data.func`.

But what if I had a dictionary of functions in data?

```
{"func" : <function func at 0x103f25410>, "dunk" : <function dunk at 0x103f25410>}
```

Is there anyway I could do something like `self.key = data[key]`? In other words, assign `func` and `dunc` with the data in the dictionary but not explicitly have to `self.func` or `self.dunc` every assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like:

```
def __init__(self, data):
    for name, func in data.items():
        setattr(self, name, func)
```

Then, you can refer to `self.func` or `self.dunc` (or whatever else was in `data`).

Comment: You're welcome, sorry about the confusion on the `setattr()` call. I blame this flu I've got. :)